# differentiate between users who are sharing login details

Tags: php, html

I currently differentiate users with `$_SESSION[id]`. But it has come to my attention that some users are sharing login details on multiple devices simultaneously. Which can cause problems on the system. If I can find a way to identify these identical session values and then differentiate them, I could solve this problem. Is there some way to get a unique code for every device? Any ideas much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can assign a random token when user authenticates. It will be different even if the same user is logged in twice.

Comment: Same rules apply for logged-in users: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940179/detecting-a-unique-anonymous-user

Comment: What kind of problems are you encountering?

Comment: Maybe the session is being prematurely recreated..? The session *should only be created if it does not already exist* or is expired and it *should not share any data with any other session*. Since *the session cookie/token is (or should be) a nonce*, then it implicitly creates a data isolation barrier between all sessions.

Answer (score 0):

You session ID is effectively a unique code for each connected client since it's a unique cookie value stored in the browser.  You could, if it's a valid requirement, limit users to only one valid session and block all other login attempts.