# If I update my web browser, will the User Agent be changed?

Tags: php, web-services, web, browser

Suppose that this is my user agent

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7) Gecko/20040803 Firefox/0.9.3
```

If I update my web browser, will this string change?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Most probably yes.

If your current version of FireFox (for example) is 30, and you update to 31 it will be reflected in the User-Agent header that is being sent to the server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you tell me if there are any data we send to the server that it is not changed frequently? For example I believe that our IP address is not a trusted answer for this..

Comment: What is it that you're trying to achieve? Why can't you rely on Cookies?

Comment: I want to hold data of the visitor and save them in my database. Every time that the specific visitor returns, I want to add 1 to the field 'visits'. I am looking for alternative ways rather than cookies.

Comment: The Canvas Fingerprinting method (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_fingerprinting) is drawing much attention nowadays. Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940179/detecting-a-unique-anonymous-user