# Concurrent unsigned users creating reviews, then sign up and retrieve the review record created by the right user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a form where user can submit a review to a product without having to log in first. When user clicks the submit button, `ReviewsController` calls `auth_user` method which creates a new `Review` object with the review content updated. But, I want to associate this `Review` object with the user who is going to sign up. Right now, I'm simply retrieving the last `Review` object like this, `Review.last`. However, I know that this is vulnerable to multiple users creating reviews and signing up at the same time. Suppose that *User A* submits a review, *User B* submits a review, and *User A* signs up. In this scenario, it will retrieve the `Review` object created by the *User B* instead of the one created by the *User A* and associate the record with the *User A*. But, I want the one created by the *User A* and associate it with the *User A* regardless of how many users are creating the records simultaneously. Does anybody have an idea of how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the IP of the request when storing the reviews and then when the user logs in, match the IP's and associate the user. You can get the IP as below

```
remote_ip = request.env["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]
```

Also you could use user agents and cookies apart from IP address. Also check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940179/detecting-a-unique-anonymous-user)