# Get browser 'installation' ID from Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome extension that sends data to a web API. I need to include some parameter into a HTTP request that would uniquely identify "a browser installation" on the client's computer. I need this ID to limit the number of requests the API accepts from a single user.

I have read the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23822170/) which are close to what I need, but not quite:

- I can't use `chrome.storage` because I want the ID to remain the same if a user removes the extension an then re-installs it
- I can't use `chrome.identity` because it requires the user to sign in, and the extension has to allow anonymous chrome users
- I can't use `chrome.system` because system information is not unique, and different computers can end up having the same ID

Answer (score 1):

Whenever possible you should encourage a user to sign in. But for tracking anonymous users I like this past question: [Detecting a “unique” anonymous user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940179/detecting-a-unique-anonymous-user)

There is no guaranteed way to track anonymous users. Systems are designed that way. Instead you can leave as many bread crumbs as possible. Someone even created an api for an extremely persistent cookie that stores itself in lots of places. [Evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/) The api is a couple years out of date, and it can be considered rude. But the concept is valid.